# CSS: how to share remaining vertical space evenly?

Tags: css

I have been trying to implement a fairly simple design all afternoon, first using flex, then just good-old divs, and am still stuck.

The HTML layout is fairly simple.

```
<div id="interface">
  <div id="toolbar">
    Toolbar<br/>Toolbar
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="main-left">
      This should take the full vertical space remaining after the toolbar,
      and half the horizontal space.
    </div>
    <div id="main-right">
      <div id="context">
        This should take half and half the remaining space after the toolbar.
      </div>
      <div id="messages">
        This should take half and half the remaining space after the toolbar.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, I would like my layout to have:

- a top `#toolbar` of unfixed height
- the rest of the screen `#main` should be split vertically at 50%

  - on the left, the entire height should be occupied by `#main-left`
  - the right part `#main-right` should be split horizontally, both parts (`#context` and `#messages`) occupying 50% of the vertical space remaining after the toolbar

The following fiddle has the elements more or less in place, but with wrong sizes.

The expected result should contain no yellow. The red area should occupy the entire vertical space. The green and purple should occupy half of the vertical space.

There should be no top-level scrollbar. If any of the red, green, purple div contents gets too large, it should just overflow within itself.

Notice how setting `#context` and `#messages` height to 50% is not correct because they become too large (it seems they become 50% of the height of `#interface`, rather than the height of `#main`)

http://jsfiddle.net/59trW/63/

Thanks for you help!

I am open to switching to flexboxes, but had similar issues there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using flexbox,

```css
html, body, #interface {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#interface, #main, #main-right {
  display: flex; /* Flex container */
}
#interface, #main-right {
  flex-direction: column; /* Column layout */
}
#main, #main-left, #main-right, #context, #messages {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute space equally among the flex items */
  overflow: auto; /* Use scrollbars if necessary */
}
#toolbar    { background-color: pink;   }
#main       { background-color: yellow; }
#main-left  { background-color: red;    }
#main-right { background-color: blue;   }
#context    { background-color: green;  }
#messages   { background-color: purple; }
```

```html
<div id="interface">
  <div id="toolbar">
    Toolbar<br/>Toolbar
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="main-left">
      This should take the full vertical space remaining after the toolbar,
      and half the horizontal space.
    </div>
    <div id="main-right">
      <div id="context">
        This should take half and half the remaining space after the toolbar.
      </div>
      <div id="messages">
        This should take half and half the remaining space after the toolbar.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's almost perfect, except that the two panes on the right do not occupy 50% of the space but something proportional to their content. I'll use this while figuring out a better solution.

Comment: @Ptival I can't reproduce that behavior. And that shouldn't happen according to the spec, so it's probably a bug of your browser.

Comment: Indeed the behavior is different in the latest Chrome and Firefox. It works the way I want in Firefox, and does the proportional thing under Chrome. Huh... Thanks!

Comment: @Ptival That's a Chrome bug. [You can fix it adding `flex-basis: 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30943274/1529630)